# Woocommerce categories display "Cannot set property 'onchange' of nul"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an error `"Cannot set property 'onchange' of null"` when I try to run this code. Why it shows `null` if it is not blank?

This code is not mine, I found it in google, but It seems to be working for others.

```
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'count'         => '0',
    'hierarchical'  => '0',
    'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts));

ob_start();

$c = $count;
$h = $hierarchical;
$o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby : 'order';
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var product_cat_dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown_product_cat");
    function onProductCatChange() {

        var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );

            if (urlmenu) {
            urlmenu.onchange = function() 
    {
    window.open(this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,'_self');
    };
}

        if ( product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value !=='' ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    product_cat_dropdown.onchange = onProductCatChange;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php

return ob_get_clean();
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an element in your html with an id of "menu1"?
If not, you have a few choices:

1. You would have to create the element with the correct id.
2. Rename the id of an existing element.
3. Change the id the script is looking for in the following line:

   `var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'newid' );`
4. If you are dealing with a situation where the aforementioned ID may or may not show up in the page, handle the undefined case like such:
   on the line which has:

   `if (urlmenu)`

change to:

```
if (typeof(urlmenu) != "undefined" && urlmenu)
```